# GoRouter navigation not working, page not opening

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `GoRouter` to navigate my app. But I ran into the following error: When I try to navigate to the `ProfilePage` then nothing happens. There is not even an error message. After looking at the documentation, I seem to have done everything right, but why doesn’t the desired page open for me on click? Who knows what the problem could be?

**route_utils**

```
extension AppPageExtenstion on AppPage {
  String get toPath {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return '/';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return '/profile';
      default:
        return '/';
    }
  }

  String get toName {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return 'Home';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return 'Profile';
      default:
        return 'Home';
    }
  }

  String get toTitle {
    switch (this) {
      case AppPage.home:
        return 'My App';
      case AppPage.profile:
        return 'My App Profile';
      default:
        return 'My App';
    }
  }
}
```

**app_router**

```
class AppRouter {
  late final AuthProvider appService;
  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;

  AppRouter(this.appService);

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: appService,
    initialLocation: AppPage.home.toPath,
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.splash.toPath,
        name: AppPage.splash.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.home.toPath,
        name: AppPage.home.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.profile.toPath,
        name: AppPage.profile.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProfilePage(),
      ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.error.toString()),
    redirect: (context, state) {
      final AuthProvider appState =
          Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: true);

      final homeLocation = AppPage.home.toPath;
      final splashLocation = AppPage.splash.toPath;

      switch (appState.loggedInState) {
        case LoggedInState.loading:
          return splashLocation;
        case LoggedInState.loggedIn:
          return homeLocation;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

**ui**

```
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Profile'),
          onTap: () {
            context.goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Use: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
context.goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);
Navigator.pop(context);
```

you issue two navigation commands:

1. Go to the profile page
2. Go one page backwards.

This seems a bit contradicting. `Navigator.pop` should not be needed in this case.

Comment: Even if I don't use Navigator.pop(context) , the page still doesn't open and there are no errors